# How to add element into another queue at once?

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I have a class which starts all the threads.

```
BlockingQueue<MyClass> otherQueue1 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<MyClass>(length);
BlockingQueue<MyClass> niceQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<MyClass>(length);
service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(length);
for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
    service.submit(new MyClass(otherQueue1, id));
}
```

In this `for` loop I would like to put this created `MyClass` onto `niceQueue`. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BlockingQueue<MyClass> otherQueue1 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<MyClass>(length);
BlockingQueue<MyClass> niceQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<MyClass>(length);
    service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(length);
    for(int k=0; k < length; k++){
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(otherQueue1, id);   #save reference in local variable
        niceQueue.add(myClass);                           #add saved reference to queue
        service.submit(myClass);                          #submit, same as in your example
    }
}
```

Comment: Could You tell me how to print things that are in queue without doing `queue.take()` to from? I need objects to stay where they are.